# React component looks like it has a static shared state within its instances

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

**Expected component behaviour:** 
- Load animation as defined by 'if' condition
- Then after 1000ms, the setTimeout function will change the state, thus rendering the 'else' part of the conditional

**Additional Details**
The component loads in fine, however, when I have another instance of the component created, both on alerts fire at the same time, and the this.render.state is set to true. This prevents the animation from loading as part of the conditional statement, since state.render is true... even though it should be false... Shouldn't each instance of this component display the default conditional behaviour?

**Name.js Component**

```
export class Name extends Component {
  state = {
    render: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    //alert('Test')
    setTimeout(
      function () {
        //Start the timer
        this.setState({ render: true }); //After 1 second, set render to true
      }.bind(this),
      1000
    );
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.render === false) {
      return (
        <div className={styles.LContainer}>
          <div className={styles.ldsRing}>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      console.log(this.state.render)
      return (
        <div className={styles.Container}>
          <img
            className={styles.imageO}
            src={require("./Apple_logo_white.svg")}
          />
          <div className={styles.textArea}>
            <h1 className={styles.title}>{this.props.title}</h1>
            <h2 className={styles.subtitle}>
            {this.props.sub}
          </h2>
          <Input name="name" handleChange = {this.props.handleChange} />
          <ScreenButton  goDirection={this.props.backScreen}  direction="back"/>
          <ScreenButton  goDirection={this.props.nextScreen}  direction="next"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**I'm also using a switch statement to render these components, could that have anything to do with it?**

```
render() {
    //Pulling information down from state:
    const { step, name, interest, location } = this.state;
    const values = { step, name, interest, location };

    switch (step) {
      case 1:
        return (
          <Welcome
            nextScreen={this.nextScreen}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            values={values}
          />
        );

      case 2:
        console.log(this.state.step);
        //return <h1>GOLS</h1>
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
          <Name
            nextScreen={this.nextScreen}
            backScreen={this.backScreen}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            values={values}
            sub="Example text"
            title="Example text"
          />
          </React.Fragment>
        );

      case 3:
        console.log(this.state.step);
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Name
              nextScreen={this.nextScreen}
              backScreen={this.backScreen}
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
              values={values}
              sub="Example text"
              title="Example text"
            />
          </React.Fragment>
        );

    }
  }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0v38.gif
```

Comment: Did you check this without `bind this` ` setTimeout(
      ()=> {
        //Start the timer
        this.setState({ render: true }); //After 1 second, set render to true
      },
      1000
    );`

Comment: Yes, it doesn't compile without the bind for some reason. I don't know why it was necessary.

Comment: are you sure, `state = {
    render: false,
  };
` this is working without putting it in a constructor?

Comment: I tired it with your suggestion, and it's the same result. The problem is it will load the animation the first time for the first component, but for the second component it does nothing. In the video you can see that the loading circle works, but when I hit next the next component should do the same loading animation but it doesn't.

Comment: see the answer, it's working. So, try increasing the timer to 5 sec then you'll be able to see the effect. Since 1 sec passes quickly on the page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news! I figured out the solution when my `<Input/>` components started to behave similarly.

The problem was that each component (both `<Name />` and `<Input/>`were behaving similarly to their first rendered instance, almost as if they were sharing state.

The fix was simple... **assign a key value for each component instance.**

Like this:
`<Name key="Unique Key Value">`

Answer (score 0):

I just checked and confirmed it's working like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class Name extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super();
        this.state = {
            render: false,
          };
    }


    componentDidMount() {
      //alert('Test')
      setTimeout(
          ()=>{
            this.setState({ render: true }); 
          },1000
      );
    }

    render() {
      if (this.state.render === false) {
        return (
          <h1>Helloooo</h1>
        );
      } else {
        console.log(this.state.render)
        return (
          <h1>Bye</h1>
        );
      }
    }
  }
```

See this: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-breeze-gdmmy?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. However I have this functionality working, but only for 1 component, when I make another component it doesn't do the same thing as the first.

Comment: I didn't get this. what do you mean by making another component? Btw did you try increasing the timer delay to see the effect?

Comment: Yes, the delay did not help. I think it is because the components are being mounted at the same time perhaps. The second component is in the switch statement.